# Discord py send random interger in embed message

Tags: discord.py

im trying to make a random number generator command for discord py which will choose a random number from what the user have send, the first number, user can input any number but the second number, user need to input the bigger number than the first number so the bot will choose a random number between the first and the second number. The command works fine but the number only choose the first or second number and not the random number between the first and second number. Heres the code :

```py
    @client.command()
    async def randomnumber(ctx):

        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.content.isdigit() and \
                   msg.channel == ctx.channel
                   
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number Generator!!", description = "<:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>", color = ctx.author.color)
        embed1.add_field(name='Type a number', value=f'First Number : Not Yet Added!!!\nSecond Number : Not Yet Added!!!', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed1)
        msg1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        embed2 = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number Generator!!!", description = "<:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>", color = ctx.author.color)
        embed2.add_field(name='Type a second number, higher number than first number', value=f'First Number : {msg1.content}\nSecond Number : Not Yet Added!!!', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed2)
        msg2 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        x = int(msg1.content)
        y = int(msg2.content)
        if x < y:
            value = (x,y)
            embed3 = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number Generator!!", description = "<:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>", color = ctx.author.color)
            embed3.add_field(name='Result number', value=f'First Number : {msg1.content}\nSecond Number : {msg2.content}\n\nYou got {random.choice(value)} <:_pTooEaassy:827076106884087818>', inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed3)
        else:
            embed4 = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number Generator!!", description = "<:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>", color = ctx.author.color)
            embed4.add_field(name='Error', value='You didnt enter the number correctly so paimon dont know what to send <:_Paimon10:827077240079777812>', inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed4)
```

I know that the problem was on the "value" one but idk what should i change there to make the bot choose a random number between the two number, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) function

```py
>>> import random
>>> values = (1, 10)  # hardcoding for demonstration purposes
>>> random.randrange(*values)  # unpacking the tuple
6
>>> random.randrange(*values)
3
>>> random.randrange(*values)
4
```